# iOS ARKit AVDepthData Returns Enormous Numbers

Tags: arkit

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but AVDepthData, which is supposed to be in meters for non-disparity data is returning HUGE numbers.  I have the code...

```
-(bool)getCurrentFrameDepthBufferIntoBuffer:(ARSession*)session buffer:(BytePtr)buffer width:(int)width height:(int)height bytesPerPixel:(int)bytesPerPixel
{
    // do we have a current frame
    if (session.currentFrame != nil)
    {
        // do we have a captured image?
        if (session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData != nil)
        {
            // get depth data parameters
            int ciImageWidth = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap);
            int ciImageHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap);
            // how many bytes per pixel
            int bytesPerPixel;
            if (session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataType == kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat16 ||
                session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataType == kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16)
                bytesPerPixel = 2;
            else
                bytesPerPixel = 4;

            // copy to passed buffer
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
            memcpy(buffer, session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap, ciImageWidth*ciImageHeight*bytesPerPixel);

            float *floatBuffer = (float*)buffer;
            float maxDepth = 0.0f;
            float minDepth = 0.0f;
            for (int i=0; i < ciImageWidth*ciImageHeight; i++)
            {
                if (floatBuffer[i] > maxDepth)
                    maxDepth = floatBuffer[i];
                if (floatBuffer[i] < minDepth)
                    minDepth = floatBuffer[i];
            }

            NSLog(@"In iOS, max depth is %f min depth is %f", maxDepth, minDepth);
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But it's returning min and max values like...

2019-06-27 12:32:32.167868+0900 AvatarBuilder[13577:2650159] In iOS, max depth is 3531476501829561451725831270301696000.000000 min depth is -109677129931746407817494761329131520.000000

Which looks nothing like meters.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, it was my memcpy.  I had to do...

```
            float *bufferAddress = (float*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(session.currentFrame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap);
        memcpy(buffer, bufferAddress, ciImageWidth*ciImageHeight*bytesPerPixel);
```